# Is it valid to return a unique_ptr pointing to a forward declared class?

Tags: c++11, c++14, move-semantics, unique-ptr

Following code does not compile with clang-700.1.81 and it's standard library:

```
#include <memory>

class something;

std::unique_ptr<something> external_function();

std::unique_ptr<something> local_function()
{
    auto thing = external_function();

    return thing;
}
```

The diagnostics by clang:

```
......./include/c++/v1/memory:2626:46: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::unique_ptr.....requested here
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY ~unique_ptr() {reset();}
                                         ^
test.cc:10:18: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::unique_ptr<something, std::__1::default_delete<something> >::~unique_ptr' requested here
auto thing = external_function();
             ^
test.cc:4:7: note: forward declaration of 'something'
class something;
      ^
```

I guess it is trying to destroy the unique_ptr after copying it as return value, but is this really necessary? It is going be moved anyways, does it need to check if it can copy before realizing that it is easier to move it?

I could of course do this easily with a naked pointer.
Is there some other way to allow a uniqe_ptr to just "pass through" a translation unit, as shown in the example, without including extra header to get the definition of class something?

------EDIT--------
Also tried with  GCC 5.3.0 and gnu libstdc++

Does not compile as well, with similar error messages.

------EDIT----

I think it is just trying to destroy the original `thing` object.
Thanks to Rudolf for the deleter idea ( a bit messy, but only option for this )
Looking at the library code I found this in unique_ptr's code:

```
        if (__tmp)
               __ptr_.second()(__tmp);
```

where `second(_tmp)` destructs the object pointed to. Even though it is never called, the compiler needs a definition to compile it. This is silly, but apparently gotta live with it.

Comment: Gabor, I wonder if you can move that pointer out of the function with std::move and if that would help perhaps?

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando `return std::move(thing)` didn't help, `return std::move(external_function());` didn't help either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

> std::unique_ptr may be constructed for an incomplete type T, such as to facilitate the use as a handle in the Pimpl idiom. If the default deleter is used, T must be complete at the point in code where the deleter is invoked, which happens in the destructor, move assignment operator, and reset member function of std::unique_ptr. (Conversely, std::shared_ptr can't be constructed from a raw pointer to incomplete type, but can be destroyed where T is incomplete).

Thus, with a custom deleter you can use a forward declared class if the full declaration is available for the deleter:

```
#include <memory>

class Foo;

class FooDeleter
{
public:
    void operator()(Foo* pInstance);
};


std::unique_ptr<Foo, FooDeleter> pFoo;

class Foo
{
};

void FooDeleter::operator()(Foo* pInstance)
{
    delete pInstance;
}
```

Comment: Bundilis So what are you exactly saying?

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando I am saying that a custom deleter that has access to the full declaration of the class solves this.

Comment: Thanks, the deleter seems a nice idea, although a bit ugly solution just to satisfy the library/compiler. I can see why it is needed for a move assignment. Still, why is it needed? Isn't a return supposed to be move construct instead of move assignment? What is being assigned to?

Comment: Anyways, a move should definitely not call the destructor of `class something`, I surely don't want that to happen...

Comment: @BuellaGábor you are not getting the full picture. Even if you move - what happens to the instance that was moved from? Even though it is empty it still needs to be destroyed so a destructor must be available. Did you assume that the move reference you gave to some move constructor or move assignment operator would just vanish?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis That seems to contradict the entire idea of unique_ptr supposed to be drop in replacement for raw pointers. That is, I can have such construct with raw pointer so I would expect to be able to have it with unique_ptr too.

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando Yes, this is messy. BTW technically in this translation unit the function `local_function` does not have ownership of the the `class something` typed object, so it shouldn't use unique_ptr. At the same time it does have ownership, cuz who else would have ownerhsip?

Comment: @BuellaGábor it looks to me like dear ISO Committee messed up again.

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando why? Its the other way around - the ability of `std::unique_ptr` to call the destructor makes it safe as opposed to raw pointers. Just step through a line like `std::unique_ptr<int> pOne(std::move(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int)));` and see how many destructor invocations you get;)

Comment: My next idea is even uglier: since I don't want `local_function` to own the `unique_ptr`, it should have a naked pointer to the `unique_ptr`. Just gotta solve exception safety and what-not...

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis The point being that unique_ptr isn't drop in replacement for raw pointer as it was "advertised" as such.

Comment: @BuellaGábor what do you mean with own? It does not own it. The ownership depends on what happens to the return value.

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando can you provide an example where it is not a drop in replacement? This is not such an example - adding a custom deleter is not something that hard.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis this *is* such example because having raw pointer I don't have to provide custom deleter.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis I mean `local_function` should not destroy stuff, it should only move stuff. Well, stuff is not a very technical term, but you get it I hope. There should be absolutely no need for a destructor here, unless the compiler finds some other return path ( exception throw, exit, or just return another unique_ptr etc.. ) but in my code sample, there is no such thing.

Comment: And by destructor I meant destructor / deleter of the forward declared object.

Comment: @BuellaGábor but as I already said - the actual destruction does not take place there. Simply the error points to that line since the object itself cannot be constructed because the `default_delete` template can not be compiled. The actual destruction will take place when returning from the move assignment, move constructor or whatever you do with the returned value.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis I see what you mean, I also accepted your answer. We just say this is very silly, and probably can't be work around because the language does not know there is no destruction needed. There is no unique_ptr in the language, the compiler just sees a template in a header file, and a runtime condition ( `if (__tmp)` in the library I use ). It is obvious to every human looking at the source, that there is no destruction needed, the code should just readjust the stack pointer, or whatever else is the equivalent on the given platform for something with automatic storage duration.

Comment: Perhaps if the language would have the concept of special destructor for "just now moved from" objects, then the library could implement a NOP destructor for unique_ptr for that case. But right now, the poor compiler just assumes the it has to instantiate the regular destructor, cuz theoretically it can have any side effects.

Comment: @BuellaGábor but what if someone does a swap in the move constructor of a class? Then if the destruction of the moved from object would be a no op then there would be a leak.

Comment: @BuellaGábor  to me it is obvious that you shouldn't really use unique_ptr in such scenario. Use raw ptr and only when you really need safety of unique_ptr use the latter.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis But then in `external_function` I would have to do `return ptr.release()` , on the receiving end I would have to do `ptr.reset(local_function())` . This is very ugly, error-prone, and mainly defeats the idea of keeping the details encapsulated.

Comment: I guess I just have to accept that in C++ one is supposed to write a lot of implementation detail in header files, and just include all headers in all translation units, even if most of them don't depend on it. Otherwise, one just has to do these ugly hacks all over the place.

Comment: Oops, my comment about `release` and `reset` was really addressed to There is nothing we can do, and not to Rudolf.

Comment: It is UB to delete something with an incomplete type if the destructor of the type is actually non-trivial (or if it has a deallocation function). That's why `default_delete` doesn't allow you to do it.